# How to convert from Lists to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been working on [discord embeds](https://github.com/lovvskillz/python-discord-webhook) together with Lists previously where I add a new discord embed column if a embed is more than 900 characters (Limitation for discord is 1020, everything above it will throw an error due to the limitation), meaning that once we reach a 900, it should create a new embed column as in the picture below

[image: Embed]

My code example I have now is set the characters limit to 10 which means if we reach a total of 10 chracters, it will createnew columns for every 10 characters reached.

The code that previously worked using Lists:

```
payload = ["40 - (8)", "41 - (14)", "42 - (45)", "43 - (10)", "44 - (11)", "45 - (23)", "46 - (74)"]

characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(payload):

    if len(item) + characterCount > 900:
        # Embed.add_embed field is to createa embed to discord.
        embed.add_embed_field(
            name="Sizes",
            value="\n".join(payload[i:j])
        )
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)

if characterCount:
    embed.add_embed_field(
        name="Sizes",
        value="\n".join(payload[i:])
    )
```

**outprint**: See the image at the top:

---

However the issue with Lists ss that I have hardcoded the key:values into a List which i'm not quite satisfied over since dict would be a better solution to do. With that I have now converted from Lists to dict:

```
payload = {"40": 8, "41": 14, "42": 45, "43": 10, "44": 11, "45": 23, "46": 74}

characterCount, i = 0, 0
for j, item in enumerate(payload):

    if len(item) + characterCount > 900:
        print("\n".join(payload[i:j]))
        characterCount, i = len(item), j
    else:
        characterCount += len(item)

if characterCount:
    print("\n".join(payload[i:]))
```

but it throws an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

and as I am aware we are not able to get indexes and slice a dict. My problem is, How can I create new discord embed column everytime we reach over 900 characters in total using dicts?

Comment: You might get more answers if you rewrite this as a pure python question. It feels like the answer is probably easy, but it's difficult to understand the intent of the question.

Comment: @Bemmu Oh okey. I will try to add more context even thought im not sure what, maybe you could say which part you might didnt understand quite well and I can try to improve that? :D

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual information.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee The reason I put a image of just embed is to visual show you what the discord embeds does to get a better look at it. With the image I pasted the code that basically represent the result in the image. Isnt that better to show than not doing it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a slice of the dictionary you can get it by creating a list from the key value pairs from `items()` method.

```
print("\n".join([f'{key} - ({val})' for key, val in payload.items()][i:]))

# output:
# 40 - (8)
# 41 - (14)
# 42 - (45)
# 43 - (10)
# 44 - (11)
# 45 - (23)
# 46 - (74)
```

Comment: That actually worked as I wanted! Looks like I am able to use the index of ```[i:] and [i:j]``` Very beautiful! :) So my guess is that you create it to a lists basically?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust that the list items() gives will always be in the same order as the dict was defined. I think that's Python implementation specific?

Comment: @Bemmu Yes, dictionary preserves the insertion order since Python 3.6 https://morepypy.blogspot.com/2015/01/faster-more-memory-efficient-and-more.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
payload = ["40 - (8)", "41 - (14)", "42 - (45)", "43 - (10)", "44 - (11)", "45 - (23)", "46 - (74)"]

dd = dict()

for i in payload:
    splitted = i.split("-")
    splitted = [i.strip() for i in splitted]
    dd[splitted[0]] = splitted[1]

print(dd)
```